# chef script ant: command not found

Tags: ant, chef-infra, recipe

i got this method inside recipe

```
script "bashbashed" do
  interpreter "bash"
  user "root"

  code <<-EOH
  cd /my/path
  ant clean
  ant build
  ant deploy
  EOH
end
```

returns

```
localhost STDERR: /tmp/chef-script20131004-5434-823zxp: line 1: cd: tarball: No such file or directory
localhost /tmp/chef-script20131004-5434-823zxp: line 4: ant: command not found
localhost /tmp/chef-script20131004-5434-823zxp: line 5: ant: command not found
localhost /tmp/chef-script20131004-5434-823zxp: line 6: ant: command not found
```

login to guest and do ant -version. 
ant is installed in the guest. am i still missing something here?

Comment: ok.. i put ant recipe in the same runlist, i thought its ok that as long as ant is already installed in guest.

    "run_list": [
      "recipe[ant]",
     "recipe[myrecipe]"
    ],

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

The error messages indicate 2 problems:

1. the path `/my/path` does not exist.
2. it does not contain path to your java ant installation in `$PATH`.

An updated version:

```
script "bashbashed" do
  interpreter "bash"
  user "root"
  cwd "/my/path"   # make sure this path exists
  path "#{ENV['PATH']}:/opt/ant/bin"  # customize to the location of your ant command

  code <<-EOH
  ant clean build deploy
  EOH
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the environment files supplied under "/etc/profile.d/*" are not sourced by the root user, this would explain why your bash script (running as root) does not have ant configured in its path.

Perhaps a simple solution would be to run the build as a normal user account?